# Не удается отправить сообщение по электронной почте log4j

Tags: java

```
package LoggersLess;

public class Loggers {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mailer().logMail("Hello");
    }
}



package LoggersLess;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Mailer {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);

    public void logMail(String mailString) {
        logger.info(mailString);
    }
}


log4j.logger.com.foo.mailer = INFO, email
log4j.additivity.com.foo.mailer = false

log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=newemailadress11.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=newemailadress
log4j.appender.email.From=newemailadress11.com
log4j.appender.email.To=vkindratishin@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Log of messages
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

> Вот ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> новая ошибка
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, что Вы столкнулись с типичным поведением gmail при попытке отправки почты через него. Можно погуглить на тему постанвоки секретных галочек, котрые позволяют слать через него почту по SMTP, ну или ... сменить почтовый сервер. Потому что с gmail бороться реально тяжело

Comment: @S.H. ошибка явно говорит, что не найдены классы. Проблема, о которой вы говорите, т.е. что SMTP API закрыто, тут ни при чем.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, не посмотрел внимательно... Хорошо, что знающий человек Роман Вам уже ответил ниже!

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, в вашем проекте нет библиотек JavaMail. Их нужно добавить.

Если используете maven, то нужно в зависимости в `pom.xml` добавить:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Если не используете мавен, то нужно скачать эти две библиотеки, и добавить их в classpath при запуске проекта.

Если вы хотите использовать уровень не `ERROR`, то нужно реализовать интерфейс `TriggeringEventEvaluator` в каком-то своем классе и этот класс указать в конфигурации `log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass`. Сейчас у вас указан несуществующий в проекте класс `TriggerLogEvent` и из-за этого возникает ошибка. Об этом говорит [документация](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html):

> By default, an email message will be sent when an ERROR or higher severity message is appended. The triggering criteria can be modified by setting the evaluatorClass property with the name of a class implementing TriggeringEventEvaluator,

Или добавьте зависимость, чтоб использовать готовый:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Добавил тепер вот такая ошибка    log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [TriggerLogEvent].

Comment: Это какая-то новая проблема. Нужен полный стектрейс.

Comment: добавил више скрин