# Как вывести лог на почту log4j?

Tags: java

Пробовал так но ошибка

```
package LoggersLess;

public class Loggers {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mailer().logMail("Hello");
    }
}



package LoggersLess;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Mailer {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);

    public void logMail(String mailString) {
        logger.info(mailString);
    }
}


log4j.logger.com.foo.mailer = INFO, email
log4j.additivity.com.foo.mailer = false

log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=newemailadress11.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=newemailadress
log4j.appender.email.From=newemailadress11.com
log4j.appender.email.To=vkindratishin@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Log of messages
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: Вы же тут спрашивали и я вам ответил. Зачем делать дубликат вопроса: [Не удается отправить сообщение по электронной почте log4j](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1352520/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5-log4j)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса